# How can I remove a file from linguist in github?

Tags: gitattributes, github-linguist

I have a golang project, but am using a bit of c++. I downloaded a header file dependency, `nlohmann/json`, and is 22875 lines long, so naturally my github languages is not showing the proper language (Go) and is instead showing c++. How can I remove the `json.hpp` from the github linguist? I know that the .gitattributes file exists and I can change the language of some files, but how can I remove a file entirely from the linguist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell Linguist to skip a file entirely. But I don't think that's actually what you want, as you don't care if it remains highlighted, right? You can **tell Linguist to ignore some files when computing language statistics**. In your case, the best way to do that would be to declare these C++ files **vendored**, with e.g.:

```
*.hpp linguist-vendored
```

See [Linguist's README](https://github.com/github/linguist#vendored-code) for more information.